# SaveChangesAsync fails and callback not executed (IdeaBlade)

Tags: entity-framework, devforce

I inherited an application built on Silverlight 4 using IdeaBlade from DevForce 2010 version 6.1.15.0.  The backend database is SQL Server 2008.  In tracking down some updates/inserts that weren't working, I discovered that I was getting the following error from the call to IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.SaveChangesAsync().

"An entity or entities containing a referenced temporary Id is missing from the list of entities provided. Missing entities include: Revision: -100.  See exception members for more details"

Additional digging uncovered the following additional information.

"The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_valuation_revision". The conflict occurred in database "XX", table "Revision", column 'RevisionID'. The statement has been terminated."

In digging deeper, I discovered the following:

1. The two main classes involved are: Valuation and Revision
2. Valuation has a collection of Revisions. On the database, this is represented by a FK on the Revision table (not null) that references the PK of the Valuation table.
3. In addition, Valuation has a reference to the CurrentRevision. This is represented on the database as a FK on the Valuation table (can be null if there are no revisions) that references the PK on the Revision table.
4. In the problem code, a new Revision object is created like so:

   `myNewRevision = new Revision { Valuation = myExistingValuation };`

   At this point, myNewRevision is an IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Entity with an EntityState of "Added".
5. After a couple of additional changes to the object, the following code is executed.

   `EntityManager.AddEntity(myNewRevision);`

   The above call to AddEntity doesn't seem to accomplish anything as the state of MyNewRevision is the same after the call as it is before the call.
6. Next an attempt is made to save the newly created Revision object.

   `SaveChangesAsync(new[] { myNewRevision }, null, RevisionCallback, null);`

   The above statement is within a try...catch block and no error is thrown, but the RevisionCallback routine is never executed. Also the EntityState of myNewRevision is still "Added" and the key is still showing as -100.
7. Then the existing Valuation object is updated with the reference to the new Revision.

   `myExistingValuation.CurrentRevision = myNewRevision;`

   This causes the EntityState of myExistingValuation to change from "Unchanged" to "Modified".
8. Finally, the code tries to save the changes to the Valuation object.

   `SaveChangesAsync(new[] { myExistingValuation }, null, ValuationCallback, null);`
9. The result of this call is that the ValuationCallback is called, but myExistingValuation is still showing as "Modified", the reference to myExistingValuation.CurrentRevision still refers to myNewRevision with a key of -100 and an EntityState of "Added". The EntitySaveOperation object returned to the callback method has Exception == null, HasError = true, and the error is the one described at the beginning of this question.  That is,

   "An entity or entities containing a referenced temporary Id is missing from the list of entities provided. Missing entities include: Revision: -100. See exception members for more details"

   and

   "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_valuation_revision". The conflict occurred in database "XX", table "Revision", column 'RevisionID'. The statement has been terminated."

   The database is not updated.

Any suggestions?  Why doesn't the callback routine from the first call to SaveChangesAsync get executed?  How can I get the updates to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd that the RevisionCallback isn't called, but it's possible the async method hasn't completed when you do the next steps.

You can't use try/catch with the async methods here, as DevForce 2010 doesn't use the newer task-based async pattern; so exceptions will be returned to your callback or completion handler, or possibly to an EntityServerError handler if one is set up for the EntityManager.

DevForce will by default save all changes to entities in cache unless you specify a save list, but that list doesn't have to contain only one item.  When you do a save of entities with temporary ids, all entities with a temporary PK or FK need to be in the save list passed to SaveChangesAsync.  DevForce will automatically handle the fixup to the FK after the save completes successfully.

Is there any reason you can't do something like the following instead:

```
myNewRevision = new Revision { Valuation = myExistingValuation };
myExistingValuation.CurrentRevision = myNewRevision; 
SaveChangesAsync(ValuationCallback);
```

Comment: Hi Kim, Thanks for your response. I tried it as suggested, but got the following error.  "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_valuation_revision". The conflict occurred in database "XX", table "Revision", column 'RevisionID'. The statement has been terminated." (It turns out this error also occurred in the unchanged version, so I'll update the original question accordingly.)

Comment: Then I guess the question is why the Revision isn't saved, and the callback is never called.  I've never seen a situation in which a callback isn't invoked.  Do you have a Saving handler on the client or an EntityServerSaveInterceptor on the server that might be interfering with the save?

Comment: There is an EntityServerSaveInterceptor, but all it does is call the base function on ExecuteSave and return the results, so it doesn't really do anything. I'm using it now to do some debugging. I'm wondering if there might have been a bug in this particular version of IdeaBlade...

Comment: We've never seen a problem with a callback not being invoked, so this was not a problem fixed in the latest 6.1.16 release.  When debugging within the save interceptor, also look to see that validation is passing, and that all PK and FK properties contain the correct temporary id(s) prior to execution of the save. You can find more information on the interceptor at http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/save-lifecycle-server.

Comment: Thanks! I got it with your help, Kim. You said fixing up FKs requires objects to be saved at the same time and you pointed me to EntityServerSaveInterceptor. It's a timing problem. An earlier change was made to the Valuation object and SaveChangesAsync was called on JUST that object. Then the Revision object was created, added to the Valuation object and SaveChangesAsync was called again. Being async, the 1st call didn't execute until after the 2nd change. It tried to update ONLY the Valuation after it had a FK to the Revision. Revision's callback doesn't happen because it hasn't saved yet.

Comment: Fixing the problem, however, is proving to be elusive. Because of how the application was designed, SaveChangesAsync needs to be called from multiple places, thus allowing the above situation to occur. I hoped that calling it without specifying entities would fix the problem (by depending on EntityState to catch all extant changes), but it seems that when the earlier Valuation change gets to the interceptor, the Valuation object references the new temp FK of -100 pointing to the Revision, but the Revision isn't being included in the "added" items, so I still get the same error. Ideas?

Comment: According to the [server-side save lifecycle events documentation](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/save-lifecycle-server), "Additional entities that need to be saved can be added to this EntityManager or entities that should not be saved can be removed before calling base.ExecuteSave()." This might work for me, but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

Comment: If the Revision has a PK with a value of -100 and is in an Added state, I can't think why it's not in the EntityManager cache - are you using multiple EntityManagers?

Comment: The documentation at the above link states about the interceptor that "DevForce creates a new instance of this class for each query performed by the server". It also says, "Note that the EntityManager returned by the EntityManager property is NOT the original client-side EntityManager on which the save request was made."

Comment: That's true.  The entities in the save list on the client - whether explicitly defined or implicitly derived - are sent to the server and imported into the interceptor's EntityManager.  An entity with an Added state should have been in the client-side EM and save list, and therefore available to the interceptor without having to requery for it.

Comment: Further debugging revealed the following…  The interceptor ExecuteSave code is hit twice.  The first time, just before executing `base.ExecuteSave();`,  Valuation has no Revision reference (FK is 0) and there is no Revision. Then, before the call to base.ExecuteSave returns, the interceptor is hit again. If I undestand the documentation correctly, this will be on a different instance of the interceptor. This time, just before executing `base.ExecuteSave();`, Valuation has a Revision FK reference of -100 and there is an added Revision. Then the base method is called. (more...)

Comment: Each of the above interceptors' states appear consistent when considered separately. But next, the first instance of the interceptor returns from `base.ExecuteSave();` with the error about the missing Revision with a key of -100. It seems that the state of the Valuation from the 2nd interceptor instance is affecting the execution of `base.ExecuteSave();` from the 1st one before it is able to complete. The 2nd instance's call to the base method doesn't complete before error handling kicks in.

Comment: It will be a bit hard, and possibly misleading, to debug here, since if you stay at a breakpoint for too long the client will see a connection timeout and do an automatic retry.  I really can't think what could be going on here, so it might be best if you sent us a repro sample.  You can send it to the IdeaBladeSupport email address.